# Need help adding background color to drop-down menu on Bootstrap theme

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

EDIT:

I resized the drop-down menu bar, removed the borders & added a box-shadow. The drop-down button is on the right side when clicked the menu opens underneath the site title on the left, here's the updated code & picture of update: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoH9U.png)

HTML:

```
<body id="page-top">

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top py-3" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">My Site</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto my-2 my-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width:991.98px) {
  .navbar-nav{
    background-color: #f0ede8;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
float:left;
  }

  .navbar-nav .nav-item{
    text-align: center  
  }
}
```

Thanks again for your help!

I'm customizing a Bootstrap theme and would like to keep my navbar transparent but have the drop-down menu have a background color when it's resized to a smaller device. I tried altering the media queries but can't seem to figure this out. I'm still trying to get the hang of Bootstrap. I've attached two screenshots of my site as reference.The first one is how the drop-down menu currently looks. The second one is how I'd like for the drop-down menu to look.

[image]
[image]

Thank you!

HTML

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body id="page-top">

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top py-3" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">My Site</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto my-2 my-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u want the menu size in half and positioned it under the title,

i just added a little code from @Shanice Morgan

```css
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
  .navbar-nav{
    background-color:gainsboro;
    border:blue 2px solid;
    float:left; /* left side */
  }
  .navbar-nav .nav-item{
    border:blue 2px solid;
    padding: 0px 10px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
  .navbar-nav{
    background-color:gainsboro;
    border:blue 2px solid;
  }
  .navbar-nav .nav-item{
    border:blue 2px solid;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, It works! I have another question, I wanted to cut the menu size in half and positioned it under the title of the site. I tried min-width: ..px !important; but it didn't workout, any suggestions? Thanks again!

Comment: *Correction, I tried to left-align the menu & it didn't work out for me.